# How to put the same value in two sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro, in Sheet1, that begins in D1. It gets a file in my computer, gets some values in a sheet of that file and puts it into a table on Sheet2.

I need the project name (the first value it gets), to also go to Sheet1

For example, if I click D5, it shows the file path in D5, and I want the project Name in E5.

Image 1: Sheet 1, where i click in D column
[image]

Image 2: Where the information goes
[image]

If it makes it easier, what I want is the value in

```
OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("B1").Value
```

I don't care if I copy the value I got in Sheet 2, but I have to find a way.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim tableName As ListObject
Dim targetRow As ListRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Target.Column = 4 And Target.CountLarge = 1 And Target.Row >= 1 And Target.Row < 500 Then

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for user file import", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*,Excel Macro File (*.xlsx),*xlsx*")

    If FileToOpen <> "False" Then

        For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Range("D6:D60")
            If FileToOpen = c.Value Then
                MsgBox ("File already connected.")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next c

        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        Set tableName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project Portfolio").ListObjects("Data")
        Set targetRow = tableName.ListRows(Target.Row - 5)
        Target.Value = FileToOpen

        With targetRow
            .Range(3) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("B1").Value
            .Range(4) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("C1").Value
            .Range(5) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("D1").Value
            .Range(6) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("E1").Value
            .Range(7) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("F1").Value
            .Range(8) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("G1").Value
            .Range(9) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("H1").Value
            .Range(10) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("I1").Value
            .Range(11) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("J1").Value
            .Range(12) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("K1").Value
            .Range(13) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("L1").Value
            .Range(14) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("M1").Value
            .Range(15) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("N1").Value
            .Range(16) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("O1").Value
            .Range(17) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("P1").Value
            .Range(18) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("Q1").Value
            .Range(19) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("R1").Value
            .Range(20) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("S1").Value
        End With

        OpenBook.Close False

    End If

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

This is ChatGPT code. I don't understand VBA.

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit about what your actual sheet names are (I don't see a "sheet1" in your code...) and tell us which is the sheet which has this event handler (i'd guess "Project Portfolio"?)  Also if you're mentioning column letters it's useful to include the column headers in your screenshots so we can see what you're referring to.

Comment: Sheet 1 is "Import" that have the D column for the file path and E for Project Name, sheet2 is Project Portfolio that hás everything Else. The entire Range from D6:D60 have the macro, so for example If i get the Path in D10, I nerd the Project Name to go in E10

Comment: What's wrong with using `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")` to access the sheet you want, and then put the value into the desired cell?

Answer (score 0):

> if i click D5, it shows the file path in D5, and i want the project Name in E5

- If `Target` is `D5`, then `Target.Offset(0, 1)` is `E5`

```vb
Option Explicit
' Import sheet event
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Dim tableName As ListObject
    Dim targetRow As ListRow, c as Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Target.Column = 4 And Target.CountLarge = 1 And Target.Row >= 1 And Target.Row < 500 Then
        FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for user file import", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*,Excel Macro File (*.xlsx),*xlsx*")
        If FileToOpen <> "False" Then
            For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Range("D6:D60")
                If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
                    If FileToOpen = c.Value Then
                        MsgBox ("File already connected.")
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
            Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
            Set tableName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project Portfolio").ListObjects("Data")
            Set targetRow = tableName.ListRows(Target.Row - 5)
            Target.Value = FileToOpen
            ' Update cell in col E w/ project name form OpenBook
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Range("B1").Value
            With targetRow
                'Extract other values
                Dim i As Long
                For i = 3 To 20
                    .Range(i) = OpenBook.Sheets("Extracts").Cells(1, i - 1).Value
                Next i
            End With
            OpenBook.Close False
        End If
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Offset property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)